# How to customize unity launcher

Tags: unity, panel, customization

I've tried to find any information about customizing Unity, here is a link to the official documentation but it didn't help for me - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Unity/Theming#Unity_Panel

Maybe I lose sight of the information that I need. So, I want to make panel looks like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wkWCW7O.png]

How I can do this?

Answer (score 7):

If I am correct, then the Firefox icon belongs to the Numix Circle theme.

To install it, open a Terminal and enter the following commands -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:numix/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install numix-gtk-theme numix-icon-theme-circle
```

Then, install the Unity Tweak Tool -

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Open the Unity Tweak Tool and click on *Theme* -

[image]

Select the theme *Numix*

[image]

Similarly, click on *Icons* and select *Numix Circle*

---

## Alternatively, if you just want to get rid of the 'tile' background -

**1.To Remove the Tiles**

First you need to get to your `~/Downloads` folder by the command:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Then download a file by the command:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/n48gz3g0fachi3t/icons.tar.gz
```

The download contains a `icons.tar.gz` file. Then make a backup of the image files at `/usr/share/unity/icons` by doing the following:

```
mkdir ~/backup_icons
cp /usr/share/unity/icons/* ~/backup_icons
```

Then get to `/usr/share/unity`:

```
cd /usr/share/unity
```

Now untar the tar file downloaded into `/usr/share/unity` by the following command:

```
sudo tar zxvf ~/Downloads/icons.tar.gz
```

**This should get rid of the 'tile'** .

**2.To add the Tile back again**

First you need to get to your ~/Downloads folder by the command:

```
cd ~/Downloads
```

Then download a file by the command:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/31ory2zycvk5c6x/icons.tar.gz
```

The download contains a `icons.tar.gz` file. Then make a backup of the image files at `/usr/share/unity/icons` by doing the following:

```
mkdir ~/backup_icons_notile
cp /usr/share/unity/icons/* ~/backup_icons_notile
```

Then get to `/usr/share/unity`:

```
cd /usr/share/unity
```

Now untar the tar file downloaded into `/usr/share/unity` by the following command:

```
sudo tar zxvf ~/Downloads/icons.tar.gz
```

**This should add the 'tile' back**.

Credits to [Andrew](https://askubuntu.com/users/48372/andrew) for this solution.

---

## To create a custom Unity launcher, refer to [this guide](http://g33q.co.za/2010/10/29/using-unity-day-4-custom-unity-launcher-colors-and-patterns/).

Comment: Thanks, I know how to apply new theme. I want to make custom Radiance theme. Just for myself.

Comment: I personally like the Moka icons from the same ppa. But that neither here nor there, but maybe you might like that- *edit* I'm an idiot. Two totally different projects

Comment: @geoffmcc Aren't Moka and Numix separate projects?

Comment: Your right, my bad. I used them both before and somewhere along lines thought they were same maker. I'm gonna go hide under my desk in shame for a while

Comment: @AntonKozlovsky I have edited the answer to include more information since I am not able to understand what exactly it is that you need.

Comment: @Rohith Madhavan I've got what I want :-)
But if future I want to make my theme and share it, so is it the only way to make clear panel without tiles or there is another way?

Comment: Just have to make new folder in iconset directory with name unity.